How to properly recluster data in a largeish Bigquery table
I have table with 2B records , 62 somewhat equal partitions, ~800GB size.
Partitioned by Month, clustered by a int64 column along with another (sub-index) int64 column.
Clustering applied at table creation.
Data got loaded from GCS usin Parquet files in random order.
Neither new data nor the old one is being clustered - no block pruning in query execution, preview shows random order.
Doing the UPDATE table SET clustered_by_id = clustered_by_id  WHERE true does not seem to solve the  problem even though I got charged for the whole 800GB.
Waited 24hrs to see if this is a background thing.
Any other tricks to making a table clustered except using standard sorted inserts through intermediate table instead of loading directly + UPDATE on clustering fieles with "where true" ?
Also a bonus question - should a MAX(clutered_by_id) scan the whole column on a properly clustered data in BQ ?
Thanks,
Tried reclustering using inplace update.

If when the table was created (either before or at loading time) and you specified clustering at that point, then the table should be clustered already.  Let us now contemplate how we can determine if clustering is working.  First, let's separate the notion of partitioning vs clustering.  Partitioning causes the rows of the table to be written into their own blocks (your words).  When you now perform a query, BigQuery can be sure that if you are filtering by the partitioning column, only those blocks that MIGHT contain the key will be examined.  Other blocks (partitions) will be ignored (pruned).   With this notion in mind, what then is "clustering".  Think of a partition ... just a single one ... now consider how the rows contained within that partition may be written ... the default ... they are written in a random order.   With clustering, they are written in a sorted order defined by the clustering columns.  This does NOT mean that there is an index on those columns ... merely that they are stored sorted.
Imagine a table that contains an English Dictionary.  We might have 26 partitions ... one for each letter of the alphabet.   Thus if you are looking for the word "google", we know that we need only look in the partition corresponding to the letter "g".  However ... there are still many words that begin with "g" ... and if we are clustered on that column ... then the rows in that partition are sorted alphabetically.   If we are looking for the row for "google"  . ... we might search through .. "gab", "gabardine", "gabarit" .... if we reach "goose" without having found "google", then we know we can stop.
The key to note here is that clustering still means walking through rows ... just knowing that we can stop early.
You asked if MAX(cluster_id) might still scan the whole table.  I'm going to say "yes" every time.  If you follow the story, then the cluster_id value that is maximial can occurr in "any" partition ... hence we have to look in any partition (assuming that we haven't also partitioned on the same column as the cluster) ... and secondly, clustering sorts the rows by the cluster value .. meaning that the LAST cluster value in a column will always be the last in the sort order (i.e. the highest in a MAX function).  As such, looking for the MAX in clustering is likely to awlays degrade to being about the same as not having clustering at all.
